# Find Encryption method and key from before and after encryption string

Tags: hash, passwords, md5, encryption

I have a database with roughly 4,000 members. I need to decrypt all their passwords so that I may re-encrypt them using MD5 and put into a new system. I have one account with before encryption and after encryption password strings so with this I assume I should be able to figure out a method and key range. I do not have access to the original source code or I would not be here.

I should mention that existing passwords vary dramatically.

User1 - qwDyP1db9iOPI

User2 - $1$.WXtDyLg$yxBPAWxzd.srEWJZfqZAY/

User3 - do8sLMoVVqxKQ

User4 - TKmnAlPe

How do I approach such a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you can't decrypt the passwords, because the passwords are not stored. What you are seeing is hashes of the password - there's no efficient way to find a password that matches a particular hash.

You can either force everyone to change their password once you have the configuration changed to use MD5 hashing, or you can generate new temporary passwords for everyone to get all the hashes replaced at once, but then they should all change them again anyway.

Those look like they probably came from Linux (the one that starts with $1$ is already an MD5 hash, the others look like the older `crypt()` DES variant style).

That's not always the case when dealing with application passwords - for example, some databases use considerably weaker credential storage - but Unix/Linux flavors have not stored actual passwords for a very long time, if ever.

Answer (score 1):

let's think. Suppose I can hack my way to your computer / DB (not an impossible task). So I have what you have - a list of all users' passwords, but encrypted. But most probably I can register to your system myself, and I know my own password. I can find its encrypted form in the DB, either by my username, or by the latest entry, so now I have the clear + encrypted pair! If I could do what you are asking, I'd have all passwords and full access to all accounts. Meaning that encrypting passwords, or data in general has virtually no additional security effect, and all I should care about is preventing unauthorized access to the data. But this is not true, so you can't :)

BTW, MD5 is not an encryption but a hash, or more correctly a digest.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like twalberg is right for the most part, but I'd like to go a step further to give you some practical advice:

1) Look at http://www.openwall.com/john/ (John the Ripper) for help getting the original passwords out of the database you have.  Note that the passwords generated may not be the original passwords (it is likely, but not certain).

Once you've gotten all of the passwords using this tool, think to yourself:  Anyone could do this.  Your users might use these passwords somewhere else.  If someone broke into your site, they could expose the people who trust you.  Your users could blame you if someone used this information to break into their other accounts.  Having the cleartext passwords around is risky *for you*.

I recommend you take this opportunity to have your users change their passwords.  Those that no longer use their accounts should probably have to go through a small verification step to regain access, so you can disable their accounts now.

2) When you generate the new password database, I recommend you at a minimum use a secure hash (E.g. SHA1 or SHA2) along with a per-user salt (random value prepended to the generated hash output in a standard way) to help secure the database from accidental exposure.

While this answer isn't efficient, it is probably practical for the most part for your current database if your actual password database has even approximately the proportions you represent.

Answer (score 1):

If you're switching away from your current system don't switch to plain MD5 - there are "rainbow tables" to crack a lot of common passwords; instead use salted/double MD5 or SHA

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your input. I will just have everyone change their passwords. I have no intention of keeping anyone's password. The goal was to not have all 4000 users have to change their passwords after migrating to the new system but it seems unavoidable. As davka pointed out, I have an account in this database and know my password and can see the encrypted version so thought that would be sufficient to develop a script that decrypts and renters the password into the new database. Thanks again.